# How to append li element, to another list

Tags: javascript, list, append, unordered

I have a list that i want to append another list on certain conditions.

The structure looks like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="list-1"><ul class="ul-1"></ul></li>
<li class="list-2"><ul class="ul-2"></ul></li>
<li class="list-3"><ul class="ul-3"></ul></li>
<li class="list-4 empty-list"></li>
<li class="list-5"><ul class="ul-5"></ul></li>
</ul>
```

I want the list-4 empty-list, to be inside the list before it. So in this case,inside list-3, if the list is empty. I have made a check to check if lists are empty, thats why the list-4 has a class callled empty-list.

Can it be done with javascript? I have had trouble researching to a solution, also because i an not 100% sure how to describe it.

Thanks

I tried something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.list');

    listItems.forEach(function (listItem, index) {
      var nextSibling = listItem.nextElementSibling;

      if (nextSibling && nextSibling.classList.contains('list-')) {
        var emptyList = listItem.querySelector('.empty-list');

        if (emptyList) {
          nextSibling.appendChild(emptyList);
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

I am still new to this sort of coding, so tried my best.

Comment: 1) Your HTML is invalid. You've got unclosed `ul` tags and also the `li` need to be within the `ul` 2. There is no `.list` element(s) in your example HTML. 3. What exactly should the output look like? It's not at all clear from your description of the goal.

Comment: Please click [edit] and post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: you need to close your ul tag <ul></ul>

Answer (score 0):

To do what you describe, you can:

1. Find the `.empty-list` `li` element. [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) can do that for you.
2. Get the `li` in front of it, and then find the first `ul` inside it.  [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling) is good for getting the previous `li` (since there can't be anything else in a `ul`), and the element-specific version of [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) is useful for finding the first `ul` within it.
3. See if that's empty via `.children.length === 0`.
4. If so, move the `.empty-list` element into it via [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) as you have in your question (or [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append)).

Here's an example:

```js
// Find the `.empty-list` element
const emptyListItem = document.querySelector(".empty-list");
// Get the `li` previous to it, and find the (first) `ul` within that `li`
const previousList = emptyListItem
    .previousElementSibling
    .querySelector("ul");
// If that `ul` has no element children, move the empty `li` into it
if (previousList.children.length === 0) {
    previousList.appendChild(emptyListItem);
}

// (Just to show the resulting structure)
console.log(document.querySelector(".menu").outerHTML);
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
<li class="list-1"><ul class="ul-1"></ul></li>
<li class="list-2"><ul class="ul-2"></ul></li>
<li class="list-3"><ul class="ul-3"></ul></li>
<li class="list-4 empty-list"></li>
<li class="list-5"><ul class="ul-5"></ul></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this code. First check which li has no children with listItem.childNodes.length===0 get its class (using className) and select it (using getElementsByClassName) then get the previous element with same approach. In this case I first check if your 'orphan' li is not the first element in case your li order changes with (index!=0). In case order changes and orphan 'li' is the first element you will

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu')
    listItems.forEach(function (listItem, index) {
      if (listItem.childNodes.length===0) {
            let className = listItem.className
            let elemToInsert = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(className))
            elemToInsert[0].remove()
            if(index!=0){
                let PrevElem = listItems[index-1].children
                className = PrevElem[0].className
                let elemToInsertIn = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(className))
                elemToInsertIn[0].appendChild(elemToInsert[0])
            }
            else if(index ===0){
                // let PrevElem = listItems[selectedIndex].children // you need to set selectedIndex
                // className = PrevElem[0].className
                // let elemToInsertIn = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(className))
                // elemToInsertIn[0].appendChild(elemToInsert[0])
            }
      }
    });
    console.log(menu)
  });
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
        <li class="list-1">
            <ul class="ul-1"></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="list-2">
            <ul class="ul-2"></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="list-3">
            <ul class="ul-3"></ul>
        </li>
        <li class="list-4 empty-list"></li>
        <li class="list-5">
            <ul class="ul-5"></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

have to select the index of the element to insert in